# How to handle the response that has a Mono<T>

Tags: spring, reactive

I have a response object like below that I need to return to the caller of my service. I need to return an instance of R.

```
public class R {
    private A a;
    private B b;
}
```

I make 2 service calls to get Mono from one and Mono from the other.

Now I am trying to make these service calls in the following manner. I do not know how I can create an instance of "C" and set the values A and B that were returned from the service calls.

```
Mono.empty()                      .concatWith(//Call that returns Mono<A>)
.concatWith(//Call that returns Mono<B>)
.??? // What do I do now? How to get A and B and 
     // set  it in a new instance of C?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Mono#zipWith`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) and then [`map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Mono<A> aMono = Mono.just(new A());
Mono<B> bMono = Mono.just(new B());

aMono.zipWith(bMono)
    .map(t -> new R(t.getT1(), t.getT2()));
```

Or `static` [`zip`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method

```
Mono.zip(aMono, bMono, R::new); // returns Mono<R>
```

Comment: Thanks caco3. One question - If any of the call errors out, will all remaining calls stop? Can I prevent this from happening by ensuring that all calls continue even if one fails?

Comment: Sure, you can. Check out [handling errors](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling) section and [A.5. Handling Errors](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors)